# I want to show tooltip of selected items for kendo Multiselect while applying tagMode property as single

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

I am using kendo multiselect and in that I have applied tagMode as single.
below is the structure of kendo-multiselect

```
$("#status-id").kendoMultiSelect({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        tagMode: 'single',
        autoClose: false,
        clearButton: true,
        dataSource: statusData
});
```

As I have applied tagMode as single, kendo-multiselect will shows count of selected items as per below screen shot,

[image]

The problem is that user not able to see which items he selected so I want to show tooltip of selected items while user mouse hover on kendo-multiselect.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the list of selected elements changes, the `change`-event is triggered. Now you can set the `title`-attribute of the MultiSelect. You can get the list of selected elements with the function `value()`. Simply call `$("#required").getKendoMultiSelect().value()` on https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/tag-mode to see an example.

Comment: This is not the answer of my question. as per mentioned screen shot it is showing "3 ITEM(s) Selected". but how user able to know which 3 items are selected. so I want to show tool tip when user do mouse hover on "3 ITEM(s) Selected" in the drop-down.

Comment: If you would use the information from my answer, you would see that it contains all the things you need to know to solve your issue. I will not give you the code so you can copy&paste it into your project. Give it a shot and let me know there are any issues on the way.

Comment: Problem Solved Thanks.

Comment: Good to know. If you want, you can update your question and add your solution so others can benefit from your efforts. Also, consider to mark my answer as accepted to help others to find a proposed solution easier.